Flask and supabase form
My client asked me to create a Flask backend using Supabase as the database, here's the problem:
Form data: {'employee': 'Alexandre Martins', 'company': 'test', 'area': 'test', 'sector': 'test', 'city': 'test', 'service': '2024-04-10', 'observations': 'Ragdgh', 'initial_complaint': 'dgfh', 'psychologist': '1'} 
These are the data I'm receiving from the frontend, and from the beginning, there was a problem. I could either process the employee query or the company query, but I couldn't fetch the IDs of both. So, I decided to separate the queries into two separate functions of the endpoint. I also decided to separate the data submission, so the structure became:
Find the company ID.
Find the employee ID.
Endpoint to register the frontend response.
Endpoint to insert into Supabase.
The responses continue to return 500 errors even though the data corresponds to the Supabase tables and matches between the frontend and backend. I never manage to query both employee and company IDs. What should I do? I know my code is messy, but I've tried everything to make it work and I'm already lost.This hole thign whas translate by a ai, so, maybe some things may not make so sense. sory.
def find_company_id(company_name):
    response_company = Client.from_('companies').select('company_id').eq('company', company_name).execute()
    print("Company query response:", response_company)

    if 'data' not in response_company or len(response_company['data']) == 0:
        raise Exception("Company not found")

    company_id = response_company['data'][0]['company_id']
    return company_id

def find_employee_id(employee_name, company_id):
    response_employee = Client.from_('employees').select('employee_id').eq('name', employee_name).eq('company_id', company_id).execute()
    print("Employee query response:", response_employee)

    if 'data' not in response_employee or len(response_employee['data']) == 0:
        raise Exception("Employee not found")

    employee_id = response_employee['data'][0]['employee_id']
    return employee_id

@app.route('/insert-service', methods=['POST'])
def insert_service():
    global form_data

    try:
        # Receive form data
        form_data = request.json

        # Call endpoint to process data and insert into the service table
        response = process_data_and_insert()
        return response

    except Exception as e:
        return {'error': str(e)}, 500

@app.route('/process-data-and-insert', methods=['POST'])
def process_data_and_insert():
    global form_data

    try:
        # Extract form data
        company_name = form_data['company']
        employee_name = form_data['employee']
        psychologist = form_data['psychologist']
        area = form_data['area']
        sector = form_data['sector']
        city = form_data['city']
        service_date = form_data['service']
        observations = form_data['observations']
        initial_complaint = form_data['initial_complaint']

        print("Form data:", form_data)
        print("Company:", company_name)
        print("Employee:", employee_name)

        # Find company ID
        company_id = find_company_id(company_name)
        print("Company ID:", company_id)

        # Find employee ID
        employee_id = find_employee_id(employee_name, company_id)
        print("Employee ID:", employee_id)

        # Insert into the service table
        response_insert = Client.from_('services').insert([
            {'employee': employee_id, 'psychologist': psychologist, 'company': company_id, 'area': area,
             'sector': sector, 'city': city, 'service_date': service_date, 'observations': observations,
             'initial_complaint': initial_complaint}
        ]).execute()

        if 'error' in response_insert:
            raise Exception(response_insert['error'])

        return {'message': 'Service inserted successfully'}, 200

    except Exception as e:
        return {'error': str(e)}, 500


Why are you storing the form data as a global var? Just pass it to the functions or access it again from the request object

Also, just saying that you get 500 errors isn't helpful for us to debug - it could be literally any error in this processing. What is the accompanying message?

I don't really know why I passed it as a global variable, at the time it seemed sensible lol but the errors are that they don't return the IDs, employee time, company time.

In which case you need to look at that. It could be anything, including a type issue (a string id instead of an int) or something. Right now the error is not descriptive enough

the log:
192.168.99.109 - - [30/Apr/2024 13:44:21] "OPTIONS /insert-service HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Form data: {'company': 'test', 'employee': 'Alexandre Martins', 'area': 'test', 'sector': 'test', 'city': 'test', 'service_date': '2024-05-02', 'remarks': 'aegdg', 'initial_complaint': 'fsgh', 'psychologist': '1'}
Company: Test
Employee: Alexandre Martins
Company query response: data=[{'company_id': 1}] count=None
192.168.99.109 - - [30/Apr/2024 13:44:21] "POST /insert-service HTTP/1.1" 500 -
As you can see, the collaborator's ID is not being printed.
